# Принцип вызова разных функций, но с одинаковыми параметрами

Tags: c++

Делема состоит из следующего, к примеру существует 2 функции [си](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8) кода, которые в свою очередь принимают одинаковые параметры, но выполняют разные действия, в моем случае локальный, и удаленный файл.

```
// Выполняет открытие файла локально.
my_data* new_path(my_super_struct* data, const char* path);

// Может работать по любому доступному протоколу, `file://some_path`
// не исключение.
my_data* new_location(my_super_struct* data, const char* mrl);
```

При передачи данных в класс, передается булевое значение откуда открывается файл, и вот тут-то и происходит проблема, что лучше использовать, адрес на функции, или `if`/`else`?

Т.е. я могу сделать вызов функций одинаково что по адресу, что через `if`/`else`:

```
void some_void(const char* file_path, bool is_local)
{
    // Первый вариант
    my_super_data = (*(is_local ? &new_path : &new_location))(some_data, path);
    // if/else не нуждается в комментировании, думаю.
}
```

В общем, насколько дурно пользоваться таким способом вызова функций?

Comment: мне кажется, с if/else будет очевиднее и более хорошо читаться. Также можно сделать табличку с указателями на функции и вызывать по индексу: `Function_t funcs[2] = {new_location, new_path}; my_super_data = funcs[is_local](some_data, path);`

Comment: С точки зрения читаемости и сопровождения кода, пример с 2-мя фукциями лучше сделать через if/else, если таких функций много, то тут есть куча вариантов. С точки зрения сгенерированного кода, тирнарный вариант против if/else будут одинаковы

Comment: "Лучше" - увы, не критерий. Вернее, не точно выраженный. Поскольку функционально это одно и то же, понятие "лучший" остается трактовать как "более краткий код" - тогда тернарный оператор, "более понятный код" - тогда, пожалуй, if/else, "код, соответствующий принятому в команде стилю кодирования" - без комментариев...

Comment: `my_super_data = (*(is_local ? &new_path : &new_location))(some_data, path);`, кстати, можно сократить до `my_super_data = (is_local ? new_path : new_location)(some_data, path);`.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше это будет  с constexpr if. [сюда](http://scrutator.me/post/2017/10/07/cpp17_lang_features_p2.aspx)
Но при условии, что is_local будет известен на этапе компиляции. Таким образом избавитесь от лишних проверок в рантайме.
А если выбирать из двух - то лучше if/else и вызывать нужную. Так как присвоение указателю новой ссылки на функцию - это лишняя операция, и как это оптимизирует компилятор - знает только конкретный компилятор.

```
my_super_data = (*(is_local ? &new_path : &new_location))(some_data, path);
```

Имя функции - уже ссылка на функцию, амперсанд будет лишним и бессмысленным.